# How to create an evet in other user calendar which I have write permision, using C#?

Tags: outlook, calendar, delegates

I am trying to create an application where I add an event in other calendar which I have write access to it. 
I was manage to create an application to send an meeting invitation. But I would like to direct add to calendar? 
Second step if the schedule was change I would like to change the event date.

Any one could give any idea in how can I create a C# code to add an event in other calendar?
Thanks for any idea!

Tried alredy sending an invitation for a meeting, this worked but it is necessary user approval, them it will not work very well for the application.

using OutLook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

```
    public void NovoAtendimento(MeetInfo nwVisit)
    {
        OutLook.Application objOL = new OutLook.Application();
        OutLook.AppointmentItem objAppt = (OutLook.AppointmentItem)objOL.CreateItem(OutLook.OlItemType.olAppointmentItem);
        objAppt.Subject = nwVisit.Titulo;
        objAppt.Body = nwVisit.Detalhe;
        objAppt.Location = nwVisit.Local;
        objAppt.Start = nwVisit.DiaInicio;
        objAppt.End = nwVisit.DiaFim;
        objAppt.MeetingStatus = OutLook.OlMeetingStatus.olMeeting;
        objAppt.RequiredAttendees = nwVisit.Email;
        objAppt.Save();
        objAppt.Send();
        objAppt = null;
        objOL = null;

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `Application.CreateItem`, retrieve the shared folder using `Namespace.CreateRecipient` / `Namespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder`, then add an appointment using `MAPIFolder.Items.Add`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your hints , I will try today, and post here the results!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your tip it worked. following the soluction I used:

Answer (score 0):

After checking the hint from Dmitry, this was the final prograns lines that worked:

```
    public void TestCheckCalendar(MeetInfo usrCall)
    {

        OutLook.Application myApp = new OutLook.Application();
        OutLook.NameSpace myNs = myApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
        OutLook.Recipient myReci = myNs.CreateRecipient(usrCall.Email);
        OutLook.MAPIFolder calFolder = myApp.Session.GetSharedDefaultFolder(myReci,OutLook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);
        OutLook.Items itemTest = null;
        OutLook.AppointmentItem appItem = null;

        itemTest = calFolder.Items;
        appItem = itemTest.Add(OutLook.OlItemType.olAppointmentItem) as OutLook.AppointmentItem;
        appItem.Start = usrCall.DiaInicio;
        appItem.End = usrCall.DiaFim;
        appItem.Location = usrCall.Local;
        appItem.Subject = usrCall.Titulo;
        appItem.Body = usrCall.Detalhe;
        appItem.Save();


    }
```